# jQuery content slider with RELATIVE links

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, dreamweaver, relative-path

I have a previously working website that uses a small jQuery script to trigger an image with the class content slide to animate when rolled over and show a div containing content when clicked and hide in when clicked again etc., this worked fine in my main pages (example: `index.html`) but does not work on my subdirectory pages (example: `subdir/code/howcssworks.html`), and I'm assuming it's due to the relative link paths no longer working.

Here is the jQuery script.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

var slideState = "closed";

$('div.content').hide();

$('img.contentslide').click(function() {
    $('div.content').toggle(1500,function() {
        if (jQuery.browser.msie) {                          // Lines 15-17 = special treatment for IE, because of  
            this.style.removeAttribute('filter');           // lack of support for ClearType font rendering on items
        }                                                   // being toggled in jQuery.
    });
        if (slideState == 'closed') {
            $('img.contentslide').attr('src','images/website/hidecontentstd.png');
            slideState = "open";    

        } else {
            $('img.contentslide').attr('src','images/website/showcontentstd.png');
            slideState = "closed";
        }
});

$('img.contentslide').hover( function() {
    if (slideState == 'closed') {
        $( this ).attr('src','images/website/showcontenthvr.png');

    } else {
        $( this ).attr('src','images/website/hidecontenthvr.png');
    }
},
function() {
    if (slideState == 'open') {
        $( this ).attr('src','images/website/hidecontentstd.png');

    } else {
        $( this ).attr('src','images/website/showcontentstd.png');
    }
}
);

return false;   // If JS is disabled - show extra content automatically 

});
```

My question is: how can I change the relative linking paths in the jQuery script so it works correctly for both the main pages and the subpages of my website?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a link like this:

```
images/website/hidecontentstd.png
```

You need this:

```
/images/website/hidecontentstd.png
```

That assumes that your `images` folder is at `yoursite.com/images`